# Using two (or more) variabels to find duplicate line in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, duplicates

Like the title suggests, I've been working on a script that I can use to find duplicate lines in a CSV file based on multiple cells using pandas.

So far I have managed to write a script that will look at one cell, and output all the duplicates as a CSV file. However, I am now having trouble adding a second cell for the script to look at.
The code I currently have looks like this:

```
    import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', sep=';', dtype=str)
names = df["FULLNAME"]
duplicates = df[names.isin(names[names.duplicated()])].sort_values("FULLNAME")

duplicates.to_csv('DUPLICATE_OUTPUT.csv')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `pd.Series`'s `duplicated` , you can use `pd.DataFrame`'s `duplicated`, which takes the subset argument.

[Reference here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)

Example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4], 'y': [1,2,3,4,1,2,5,6], 'random': [1,3,143,15,1,3,2,1]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   random  x  y
0       1  1  1
1       3  2  2
2     143  3  3
3      15  4  4
4       1  1  1
5       3  2  2
6       2  3  5
7       1  4  6

In [4]: df[df.duplicated(['x', 'y'])]
Out[4]: 
   random  x  y
4       1  1  1
5       3  2  2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 

So, sorry for the stupid follow up question, but how would I go about using this to look at two specific columns in a csv file and then outputing both?

Thanks again!

Comment: Edited my original answer, hope it helps.